# Handling NULL values in DAX Query to get distinct Items from multiple Tables

Tags: powerbi, dax

```
TravelCategory = DISTINCT(UNION(VALUES('CrossCutting'[Travel_Category]), VALUES( 'EntitlementTravel'[Travel_Category]), VALUES( 'HRTravel'[Travel_Category]),VALUES( 'OfficialTravel'[Travel_Category])))
```

I have the above table which gives me a distinct list of **Travel_Category** from 4 different tables.

How can i set a default value if the **Travel_Category** is NULL for a row in any of the tables above?

Answer (score 2):

Try this for each column:
 `if (isblank('CrossCutting'[Travel_Category]), "Your_Default_Value", 'CrossCutting'[Travel_Category])`